# Github Repository - LockFile Exists

Tags: android, git, github, github-for-mac, github-desktop

I recently tried to commit to my repository via GitHub Desktop and was told there is a lock file preventing me from doing so. I do not recall uploading this lock file nor do I have an idea where it came from:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might someone else pushed at the same time?
Else, just try to stash changes, move to another branch, move back, apply stash and push again.

Comment: Everything was freezing up, I restarted the computer, and tried committing again, so yes if there was another commit "pending," that may be the cause

Answer (score 3):

I followed these steps and it works for me. Thanks

- Enable the viewing hidden files and folders on Windows.
- Go to your hidden .git directory shown in the error message
- Delete the index.lock file located there.
- After deleting the index.lock file you can do commit using GitHub Desktop again.

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable the viewing hidden files and folders on Windows.
2. Go to your hidden .git directory shown in the error message
3. Delete the index.lock file located there.

After deleting the index.lock file you can do commit using GitHub Desktop again.