I am getting "A Lock file already exists in the repository, which blocks this operation from completing." when using GitHub Desktop
I get this error when I try to fetch or when I try to switch branches.  Everything I have read online says that I need to delete the index.lock file in the hidden .git directory in my repository.  The trouble is that the file doesn't exist.  The index file is there, but not the .lock file.
I can switch branches or fetch just fine from the command line or from Xcode.  I tried deleting and re-installing GitHub desktop, but it is still showing the warning.
Any ideas on how to reset GitHub desktop, it really seems like the problem is with it, but I have no idea how to resolve it.

Is the repo on a shared drive, such as iCloud Drive, Google Drive, etc?

It is just on my Mac's hard drive in the documents folder.

OK, that's fine! Just wanted to make sure nothing was interfering with the repo's internals. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66451786/341994 for more about why this can mess things up. — I think what I'd advise is: since the command line works, just use the command line. A Git GUI can be useful sometimes for visualizing the history topology but personally I always use the command line (and never Xcode, though to be sure its blue change bars are very helpful and I do like seeing them).

If you really really insist on getting GitHub working, then just push all local branches as needed, then delete the local repo and make a new clone. But I honestly have no idea why you don't see any lock file is GitHub says there is. Note that it need not be index.lock — any lock file would be problematic here.

Try the command find . -name *.lock in git-bash. Run the command under the repository root path.

Thanks @matt & ElpieKay.  No lock file of any flavor.  It is really strange.  I just like GitHub Desktop for the convenience, and did pull a fresh clone and am back in business, but would really like to understand what is going on with this.  So weird.

Try the command below in your repository command window; it will remove any locked branches, if any.
git remote prune origin

Some branches may not be removed if they have already been deleted from the main git. In that case, we need to remove them manually and try running the command again in the command window.

try find if
.git/refs/remotes/origin/upload.lock


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
